# Insert a separating space when a number is immediately followed by a letter in text

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I need to separate substrings where a number is immediately followed by a word.

```
$input = 'new stackoverflow 244code 7490script design'; 

$output = "new stackoverflow 244 code 7490 script design";
```

How can I add a space to separate numbers from letters?

Comment: How about something like `preg_replace('/(\d)(\w)/', '$1 $2', $arr);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) ([Example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/GFnExd)):

```
$arr = "new stackoverflow 244code 7490script design"; 
$newstr = preg_replace('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i', ' ', $arr);
echo $newstr; // new stackoverflow 244 code 7490 script design
```

The `regex pattern` used from `user1153551`'s answer.

Comment: can possible to separate this statement **"new stackoverflow code244 script56666 design"**

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[preg_split()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)** function

Check <kbd>**[demo Codeviper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/EJw7YP)**</kbd>

```
preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i', "new stackoverflow 244code 7490script design");
```

#### PHP

```
print_r(preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i', "new stackoverflow 244code 7490script design"));
```

#### Result

```
Array ( [0] => new stackoverflow 244 [1] => code 7490 [2] => script design )
```

---

You can also use **[preg_replace()](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gN2knV)** function

Check <kbd>**[demo Codeviper](http://codepad.viper-7.com/gN2knV)**</kbd>

#### PHP

```
echo preg_replace('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i', ' ', "new stackoverflow 244code 7490script design");
```

#### Result

```
new stackoverflow 244 code 7490 script design
```

Hope this help you!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_replace`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace) like this:

```
$new = preg_replace('/(\d)([a-z])/i', "$1 $2", $arr);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/lN5sR7)

`(\d)` match and catches a digit. `([a-z])` matches and catches a letter. In the replace it puts back the digit, adds a space and puts back the letter.

---

If you don't want to use backreferences, you can use lookarounds:

```
$new = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])/i', ' ', $arr);
```

If you want to replace between letter and number as well...

```
$new = preg_replace('/(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])|(?<=[a-z])(?=\d)/i', ' ', $arr);
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/gT6kJ1)

`(?<=\d)` is a positive lookbehind that makes sure that there is a digit before the current position.

`(?=[a-z])` is a positive lookahead that makes sure that there is a letter right after the current position.

Similarly, `(?<=[a-z])` makes sure there's a letter before the current position and `(?=\d)` makes sure there's a digit right after the current position.

---

An different alternative would be to split and join back with spaces:

```
$new_arr = preg_split('/(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])/i', $arr);
$new = implode(' ', $new_arr);
```

Or...

```
$new = implode(' ', preg_split('/(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])/i', $arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

[preg_split](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)

preg_split — Split string by a regular expression

```
<?php

      // split the phrase by any number of commas or space characters,
     // which include " ", \r, \t, \n and \f

    $matches = preg_split('#(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])#i', "new stackoverflow 244code 7490script design");

    echo $matches['0'],' '.$matches['1'].' '.$matches['2'];



    ?>
```

<kbd>**[WORKING DEMO](http://codepad.org/8c8I4r0E)**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I don't endorse the use of `preg_split()` for this task, it only make more work before eventually repairing the input string.

`preg_replace()` is the correct too, but using two lookarounds on every step will make the regex engine work harder than it needs to.  For best efficiency, greedily match one or more digits, forget them with `\K`, then lookahead for a single letter.

Instead of `/(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])/i` which [takes 87 steps on the input string](https://regex101.com/r/oWRoFV/2).

Use `/\d\K(?=[a-z])/i` which [takes only 32 steps on the input string](https://regex101.com/r/oWRoFV/1).

PHP Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/0CVB0))

```
$string = 'new stackoverflow 244code 7490script design';
echo preg_replace('/\d+\K(?=[a-z])/i', ' ', $string);
// new stackoverflow 244 code 7490 script design
```

p.s. Another viable way is `/(\d)([a-z])/i`, but this takes 39 steps and requires two backreferences in the replacements string.